# Pokemon battles on PHP website

Tags: php, state

I am a C# web programmer but I wanted to create a pokemon battle website in PHP, where users can battle online using web sockets. If you are not familiar with pokemon, just imagine it's an online player-vs-player chess website; it's sort of the same thing.

My question is where to save the pokemon (or chess) battle state/data, such as the health of each pokemon, etc (or the position of the chess pieces, using the chess analogy).

Saving it in the database seems really inefficient, as the data changes real time as people play and long-term persistence is not important; as soon as the battle is over, all data becomes useless. It's not a big deal if the data is lost if the server goes down.

If I were to do this in C#, I would just keep the data in static classes (which persists through requests, and is kept in RAM)..

In PHP, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Stick it into a RAM table in a database? All the common ones support that these days. MySQL (free option) can do that easily - and you just reference it as if it were a table.

Comment: You are going to have to cache them all.

Comment: @Fluffeh: I could, but the data would be sort of unfriendly to store in a database, it fits much more easily in normal variables and it would be less work for me if it could be saved in $variables that somehow persist through requests

Comment: If it's Player versus computer then PHP sessions should be fine.  If it's PVP you'll need something to store the data on the server, anything from a file, to a database to memcache etc

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using memcached. PHP unfortunately does not have application level variables like ASP/ASP.NET, so this is the next best thing. It is only a little bit more difficult than a static variable however.

Take a look at the PHP documentation to see how to get started: http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.examples-overview.php